# Soflayer Billing API using Ruby- Extracting per user billing details

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Have a question about Softlayer billing API. When I try to run the API code to extract the data into an object mask I receive an error as below:

**/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/softlayer_api-3.2.1/lib/softlayer/APIParameterFilter.rb:82:in `object_mask': object_mask expects strings (ArgumentError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/softlayer_api-3.2.1/lib/softlayer/Service.rb:156:in`object_mask'
    from testAuthentication_old.rb:53:in `'**

```
require 'softlayer_api'
require 'pp'

user_id = "your user id"
 api_key = "your API key"

object_mask = {"orderItem" => {"order" => {"userRecord" => {"username" =>   ""}}},
"invoiceItem" => {"totalRecurringAmount" => ""}}

billing = SoftLayer::Service.new("SoftLayer_Account",:username => user_id,:api_key => api_key)
user_bill=billing.object_mask(object_mask).getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems

pp user_bill
for item in user_bill do
if item.key?("orderItem") &&
item["orderItem"]["order"]["userRecord"]["username"] == ""
pp("User " + "" + " has an invoice item of " +
item["invoiceItem"]["totalRecurringAmount"].to_s())
end`
```

The authentication worked okay but somehow its complaining of the object mask. Can you please provide insight. In a different post on Softlayer there was a mention in changing Billing APIs. If so, do i need to define the object mask differently? Can you please let me know? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [SoftLayer API for Ruby](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-ruby) is expecting a string in the object_mask and not an object that is shows in the example specified [here](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Ruby).

Anyway, try this mask please:

```
object_mask = "mask[orderItem[order[userRecord[username]]], invoiceItem[totalRecurringAmount]]"

billing = SoftLayer::Service.new("SoftLayer_Account",:username => user_id,:api_key => api_key)
user_bill=billing.object_mask(object_mask).getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems
```

I will let you know if the other masks (object type) are not longer supported by the client.

Comment: The changes suggested above worked. We are able to display the data now. Thank you very much Ruber. Appreciate the quick turnaround